# Convert json to object in stream

Tags: scala, jackson, akka, akka-stream

I'm attempting to convert a json string :

"{"payload": "[{\"test\":\"123\",\"tester\":\"456\"}," +
"{\"test1\":\"1234\",\"tester2\":\"4567\"}]"}"

to it's case class equivalent which I have defined as :

```
  case class PayloadElements(@JsonProperty("test") test: String, @JsonProperty("tester") tester: String)

  case class Payload(@JsonProperty("payload") payload: Array[PayloadElements])
```

but receive error :

```
2022-10-06 09:41:37,248 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
2022-10-06 09:41:38,220 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] ERROR akka.stream.Materializer - [Error] Upstream failed.
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `[LTestMapper$PayloadElements;` out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: (String)"{"payload": "[{\"test\":\"123\",\"tester\":\"456\"},{\"test1\":\"1234\",\"tester2\":\"4567\"}]"}"; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: TestMapper$Payload["payload"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
```

Here is my code :

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper


object TestMapper extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  val om = new ObjectMapper
  val flow = Flow[String].map(x => om.readValue(x, classOf[Payload]))
  val sink = Sink.foreach[Payload](x => println(x))
  var str = "{\"payload\": \"[{\\\"test\\\":\\\"123\\\",\\\"tester\\\":\\\"456\\\"}," +
    "{\\\"test1\\\":\\\"1234\\\",\\\"tester2\\\":\\\"4567\\\"}]\"}";

  case class PayloadElements(@JsonProperty("test") test: String, @JsonProperty("tester") tester: String)

  case class Payload(@JsonProperty("payload") payload: Array[PayloadElements])

  val graph = Source.repeat(str).take(3).via(flow).log("Error").to(sink)

  graph.run()
}
```

Have I defined the case class structure incorrectly ?

Comment: For one thing, there's no way `{ "test1": "1234", "tester2": "4567" }` is going to deserialize to a `PayloadElements`.

Comment: Anyway, if using Scala, my strong recommendation is to not (at least not directly) use Jackson for JSON, but use a native-to-Scala JSON library (e.g. Play, Circe, Spray).

Comment: @LeviRamsey ok, thanks. I will open a new question which will narrow the focus.